# SQLDelight android/ios . Case insensitive select

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm, sqldelight

I use SQLDelight in my kotlin multiplatform app.
It works fine.
But i see a problem with case insensitive select requests. It doesn't work on iOS.

I used the tutorial to integrate SQLDelight in my app https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-configure-sqldelight-for-data-storage.html.

I have the query like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE caseInsensitiveField like '%VaLuE%'
```

In the SQLDelight file it is described as

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE caseInsensitiveField like ('%' || :filter || '%')
```

I need this select work for all char cases. It works fine on Android. But it doesn't work on iOS. Select is case sensitive.

I tried the trick from the web

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE UPPER(caseInsensitiveField) like UPPER('%' || :filter || '%')
```

It still works fine on androidn, but not on iOS.

NOTE. I tested with non-latin textx - with cyrillic

How can i make it to work on iOS? Maybe it is something with encodings?

**Update 1**.
I found the recomendation to use special pragme to get it working.

```
private val DB = Database(databaseDriverFactory.createDriver().apply {
    execute(null,"PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=OFF;",0)
})
```

But it doesn't affect. And it breaks androd selects too (not sure why, it seems internally sqlite uses some different LIKE function)

**Update 2**.
I also tried COLLATE NOCASE to be added to the end of a query. It doesn't work too on iOS

**Update 3**.
Finally, i have found that on iOS sorting of select also doesn't work! But maybe it is problem only for non-latin texts. I have my data in cirylic alphabet (ukrainian).

Comment: I don't know what's causing it. It would be a lot easier to repro and fix if you had a little sample project to share and added an issue to https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/ (I'll probably be the one working on it)

Comment: It is possibly an encoding issue, but also sqlite is compiled with various flags when built, and the details of the Android version compared to the iOS version can differ, so it might be something there as well (although less likely).